# Different parent object depending on its undefined children

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have two objects:

1. `parent1.child`
2. `parent2.child`

If child is undefined in `parent1`, I want to use `parent2` as parent object (because it'll have the child defined).

**Done this way (ES2015):**

```
const conditionalParentObj = (key) => {
  parent1[key] === undefined ? parent2[key] : parent1[key];
}
```

(Or `typeof parent1[key] === 'undefined'`, whatever)

### But how about nested children?

`parent2.child.innerchild`

Same logic: If `innerchild` is `undefined` in `parent1`, use `parent2`.

But how can I make it work without using a *weird conditional logic* like passing an `innerKey` argument to `conditionalParentObj` and return like `parent2[innerKey][key]` if `innerKey` is passed?

Comment: May be of interest – [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: It seems definitely easier that way!